# Prove that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{(t+a)(t+b)}dt$ is convergent.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $a,b>0$. I have to prove that $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{(t+a)(t+b)}dt,$$
is convergent. I have some difficulties.

- For $\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{(t+a)(t+b)}dt$, I did as follow : $$\left|\frac{\ln(t)}{(t+a)(t+b)}\right|\leq \frac{\ln(t)}{t^2},$$
  and since $$\frac{\ln(t)}{t^{2}}=\mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{t^{3/2}}\right),$$
  and that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t^{3/2}}dt$ converges, the integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{(t+a)(t+b)}dt$ converges.
- I have difficulties for $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(t)}{(t+a)(t+b)}dt$. I tried the majoration $$\left|\frac{\ln(t)}{(t+a)(t+b)}\right|\leq -\frac{\ln(t)}{t^2},$$
  but $-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(t)}{t^2}=+\infty $. Any idea on how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0<t<1$,

$$\left|\frac{\ln t}{(t+a)(t+b)}\right|\le\frac{|\ln t|}{ab}$$

Comment: ok, good job :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that by letting $t=1/s$,
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(t)}{(t+a)(t+b)}dt=-\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\ln(s)}{(1+as)(1+bs)}ds$$
Now, since $a,b>0$, you may follow the same approach used for the interval $[1,+\infty)$.

Comment: Nice answer as well :)